# Can I connect to an ODBC database from a web-based application?

Tags: odbc

Is it possible to connect with an ODBC database from a web-based application? Or does the application have to be downloaded directly on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For example, the [odbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc) npm package is available for Node programs (and such a program could easily be the backend for a web application). The original ODBC design was intended to be an "open" API, independent of implementation concerns such as operating system and database.